# fotorama: can't get the API object (undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

I'm using Fotorama 4.5.0 (Rails gem) and I have a problem with getting the API object.

On page load Fotorama is in hidden div. It opens in modal on click.
Here is the code (coffee):

```
$objects = $('*[rel="fotorama"]')
$fotorama_div = $('.fotorama')

$fotorama_div
.on('fotorama:showend', (e, fotorama, extra) ->
  // resizing fotorama
).fotorama()
fotorama = $fotorama_div.data('fotorama')
console.log(fotorama) // here is undefined

$objects.on 'click', ->
  // finding index of an image
  modal.open({content: $('#fotorama-container')})
  fotorama.show(index) // index is ok
```

With this code `fotorama` object is always `undefined`.
Ok, I added `if` with check:

```
$objects = $('*[rel="fotorama"]')
$fotorama_div = $('.fotorama')

$fotorama_div
.on('fotorama:showend', (e, fotorama, extra) ->
  // resizing fotorama
).fotorama()
fotorama = $fotorama_div.data('fotorama')
console.log(fotorama) // here is undefined

$objects.on 'click', ->
  // finding index of an image
  modal.open({content: $('#fotorama-container')})
  if typeof fotorama == "undefined"
    fotorama = $fotorama_div.data('fotorama')
    console.log(fotorama) // here is undefined after the first click on object
  fotorama.show(index) // index is ok
```

After the first click on object — `fotorama` is still `undefined`, but after I'm closing a modal and doing the second click — I get `fotorama` object and everything works as expected.

And when I doing `$fotorama_div.data('fotorama')` in console, it works.

How can I get `fotorama` object on page load?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem - loading fotorama in a div gave "undefined" in console, only after showing the div again the fotorama object was loaded correctly.

I found the cause of this was loading fotorama in an object with "display: none;" css styling. I dont know why but if fotorama loads in something that is hidden then it breaks.

I dont know any RoR but my sugestion would be to first show the modal, then load fotorama `$fotorama_div.fotorama()` after the modal is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the reason why it returns `undefined`.

If the `$fotorama_div` has `style="display: none;"` attribute then `$fotorama_div.data('fotorama')` will return `undefined`.

So the solution is to remove this attribute `style="display: none;"` before you run `$fotorama_div.data('fotorama')`.

```
$fotorama_div.show().data('fotorama');
```

If it still returns `undefined` then check if any parents of `$fotorama_div` has `display: none` css.

```
let hiddenParents = $fotorama_div.parents().filter(function() { 
    return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
});
hiddenParents.show();
let fotorama = $fotorama_div.data('fotorama');
hiddenParents.hide();
// Now enjoy with your fotorama from here.
```