# Image swatches working on every product page except one in particular

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama, media-type

I've been looking at the console errors but I'm not sure exactly what's happening here.

Here are the images when i click on the secondary color/style on the right.

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
newportbybarclaybutera-nbb03.html:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mediaType' of undefined
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._setThumbsIcon (fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:25)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._setThumbsIcon (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._initFotoramaVideo (fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:23)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._initFotoramaVideo (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._initialize (fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:11)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._initialize (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._setOptions (fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:1)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._setOptions (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.option (widget.min.js:26)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (widget.min.js:19)
```

I read that it could be because of bundling js or css but i can't replicate this error on any other page. Needless to say i turned the bundling off just to check.

I also read that it could be because some JS in the footer needs to be moved back to the header. I tried this as well.

I'm kind of horrible at frontend development. Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

I removed the extension which happened to be last past. But it still not working and i'm still getting the error. Just no more chrome error. heh

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mediaType' of undefined
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._setThumbsIcon (fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:25)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._setThumbsIcon (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._initFotoramaVideo (fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:23)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._initFotoramaVideo (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._initialize (fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:11)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._initialize (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._setOptions (fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:1)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._setOptions (widget.min.js:15)
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.option (widget.min.js:26)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (widget.min.js:19)
_setThumbsIcon @ fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:25
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js:15
_initFotoramaVideo @ fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:23
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js:15
_initialize @ fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js:15
_setOptions @ fotorama-add-video-events.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js:15
option @ widget.min.js:26
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js:19
each @ jquery.min.js:28
each @ jquery.min.js:16
$.fn.<computed> @ widget.min.js:19
updateBaseImage @ swatch-renderer.min.js:48
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js:15
_super @ widget.min.js:15
updateBaseImage @ swatch-renderer.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js:15
_loadMedia @ swatch-renderer.min.js:25
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js:15
_OnClick @ swatch-renderer.min.js:12
(anonymous) @ widget.min.js:15
(anonymous) @ swatch-renderer.min.js:24
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:338
elemData.handle @ jquery.min.js:311
nrWrapper @ newportbybarclaybutera-nbb03.html:5
```

Comment: `Could not load content for chrome-extension` seems to be an indication... ;)

Comment: I was thinking that when i saw it but why would it work on all the other pages? You think on this particular page I just have a chrome extension that is breaking it? @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: I really can't tell. But I just landed on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211016/fotorama-cant-get-the-api-object-undefined) which may help. Good luck!